# How can I resolve this 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error?

Tags: iphone, nsurl, didselectrowatindexpath, unrecognized-selector

The error reads `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MObject objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`. So, what I get out of that is that an instance of MObject (a subclass of NSObject) is receiving an `objectAtIndex:` message that it isn't meant to handle.

The error occurs when I tap on a table row to go to its detail view, which consists of a UIWebView `detailWebView`. The code for `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is as follows:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
MObjectDetailVC *mObjectDetailVC = [[MObjectDetailVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MObjectDetailVC" bundle:nil];
mObjectDetailVC.detailURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[[mcData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] url]];
mObjectDetailVC.title = [[[mcData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mObjectDetailVC animated:YES];
[mObjectDetailVC release];
}
```

It's taking the NSString `url` property of the selected instance of `MObject` and turning it into an NSURL for the detail view controller, which just does the basic `[detailWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:detailURL]]`.

If you have any suggestions, I'll be glad to hear them. And if you need further information, please let me know.

Comment: What's the structure of `mcData`? Really an NSArray of NSArray?

Comment: `mcData` is an `NSArray` made up of a bunch of `MObject`. So, instead of each item being an `NSObject` within the array, each needs to be an `NSArray` within the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the structure of `mcData`. It and its members are expected to be NSArrays according to your code, be sure that they are.

Comment: `mcData` is an `NSArray` made up of a bunch of `MObject`. So, do you mean that instead of each item being an `NSObject` within the array, each needs to be an `NSArray` within the array?

Comment: the way the code is currently written, that is what is expected, yes. see the `[[mcData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` line, it expects an array in an array.

Comment: Hm, that's not what I intended. How can I change it so that it doesn't look for a nested array, but just takes the `url` and `name` from the selected object? Or is this possible?

Comment: i'm going to guess `[mcData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` by itself would do the trick. this assumes you have a table with a single section.

Comment: Awesome, that took care of that error. I have another one now, though. "view outlet was not set." Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`objectAtIndex:` is defined on a `NSArray`. If the `MObject` class is a subclass of `NSObject`, then it will not have the `objectAtIndex:` method defined, which is what the error says.

Both the following calls would cause a crash:

```
mObjectDetailVC.detailURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[[mcData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] url]];
mObjectDetailVC.title = [[[mcData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name];
```

Make sure that both `mcData` and `[mcData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]` return an object of `NSArray` or of its subclass.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a check to prevent the crash via respondsToSelector:

You can read more at
 `http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html`

Putting a check before passing a particular message will help you to avoid crash.